# Creating Form Classes Symfony2

Tags: php, forms, symfony, phpstorm

I have problem with creation form classes. I use this link http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#creating-form-classes 
but in phpstorm I have error
[image]

Symfony 2.8.4, phpstorm 9.0.2. What's wrong I do?
**UPD**
 I found topic, with same problem [Symfony2 Form folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12343621/symfony2-form-folder) 
but I don't see solution there.
**DefaultController.php**

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use AppBundle\Form\TaskType;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;


class DefaultController extends Controller
{


    /**
     * @Route("/task")
     */
    public function new1Action()
    {
        /**
         * @var TaskType $task
         */
        $task = new TaskType();
        $form = $this->createForm(TaskType::class, $task);
        return new Response('1');
    }
}
`
```

**UPDATE** I don't know what happened, but after I have done all recommendations  and reloaded computer this problem was solved.I don't know what is helped.

Comment: What does the error say ? Did you try to delete your form and re-create it ?

Comment: In controller I am writting code `use AppBundle\Form\Type\TaskType;` and after that a have `Attempted to load trait "TaskType" from namespace "AppBundle\Controller\AppBundle\Form\Type".` / yes, I tried to re-creat form, but it didn't help.

Comment: **""AppBundle\Controller\AppBundle\Form\Type"** This is weird.. Your instance of the form in the controller is like : `new \AppBundle\Form\Type\TaskType()` in addition of the use, or just like : `new TaskType()` ? And did you try to generate the form with the console ?

Comment: No I didn't generate this code from console. I took all code from http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#creating-form-classes and added in my code.

Comment: Possibly some re-parsing problem (especially considering that you are using old PhpStorm v9 .. while the latest version is 2016.1 (which is v11)). Try restarting IDE. If still no difference -- `File | Invalidate Caches...` and restart IDE. -- that's for the error on your screenshot only. It should not cover your other `Attempted to load trait "TaskType" from namespace "AppBundle\Controller\AppBundle\Form\Type"` error message

Comment: @LazyOne I tried to clear cache, but it doesn't work...

Comment: Well..Your code seems right.. Try the solution of Lazy. Otherwise delete your TaskType and try this command : `php app/console doctrine:generate:form AppBundle:Task`

Comment: I have error :`c:\xampp1\htdocs\first_project
# php app/console doctrine:generate:form AppBundle:Task
  [Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException]
  [Semantical Error] The annotation "@ORM\Entity" in class AppBundle\Entity\T
  ask was never imported. Did you maybe forget to add a "use" statement for t
  his annotation?
` and I took code  from http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#creating-a-simple-form

Comment: Well the message is explicit. Do you have `use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;` in your entity? When you use a class of a different namespace, you have to import this class with a **use** statement

Comment: After adding `use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;` the from has created sucesfully from console

Comment: And you still have the phpstorm's error ?

Comment: yes, I still have error in phpstorm, and I can't use  `use AppBundle\Form\TaskType;` in controller

Comment: well i don't know, try with an other IDE or with sublim Text.

Comment: Can you edit your post and put the code of your controller please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109818/discussion-between-letsrocks-and-vadim-k).

Comment: How shall this abandoned page be resolved?